# $\ell^p \subset c_0$ with continuous injection.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1 \le p < \infty$. How do I see that$$\ell^p \subset \left\{x ; \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = 0\right\}$$with continuous injection?

Comment: By considering the formal identity operator between the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$ \|id (x_{n})\| _{sup} \le sup {x_{n}} \le \|(x_{n})\|_{\ell^{p}}$ and the Cauchy criterion for convergence of the norm in ${\ell^{p}}$